# Define row of data based on search criteria in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to set a row as a range based on a search criteria.  I know which column I want to search and based on that I want that specific row to be the data range.  Once the data range is set I format it as a table and send an email with the table in it.  The code I have is pretty messed up by all the different attempts I have made so I don't have any to post. Below is just a sample of the row and column N is what I am searching on.  Then I want that row with D - Y as my range.  So search for MLS/MRL Weekend which is row 89 and set range D89:Y89 as the range based off of the search.  This is not pretty.. I am learning as I go and this really new territory for me.

```
    function rowOf(team1, dataRange) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("spreadsheetid");
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Stats1");
 var dataRange = sheet1.getSheetValues(1,14,150,1);
 var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("otherspreadsheetid");
 var sheet = ss1.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
 var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 var email = data[0][2];
 var team1 = data[0][1];
 var subject = team1 +" Team Stats";
 var outRow = null;

 for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++)
 {
   if (dataRange[i][0] == team1)
   {
     outRow = i+1;
     break;
   }
 }
 var Header = sheet1.getRange('d1:y1').getValues();
 var u13gneongoalsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,4).getValues();
 var u13gneonshotsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,5).getValues();
 var u13gneontopg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,6).getValues();
 var u13gneontop1g1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,7).getValues();
 var u13gneonfirstg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,8).getValues();
 var u13gneonpassesg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,9).getValues();
 var u13gneonpasscompg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,10).getValues();
 var u13gneonnumpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,11).getValues();
 var u13gneonavgpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,12).getValues();
 var u13gneonlongpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,13).getValues();
 var u13gneonogoalsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,16).getValues();
 var u13gneonoshotsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,17).getValues();
 var u13gneonotopg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,18).getValues();
 var u13gneonotop1g1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,19).getValues();
 var u13gneonofirstg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,20).getValues();
 var u13gneonopassesg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,21).getValues();
 var u13gneonopasscompg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,22).getValues();
 var u13gneononumpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,23).getValues();
 var u13gneonoavgpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,24).getValues();
 var u13gneonolongpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,25).getValues();


 //if (game1choice(team)) {
 var message = '<HTML><BODY><p>';
 message +=   '<table border="1">';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center"><b>U13G Neon</b></td><td align="center"><b>Game Totals</b></td><td align="center"><b>'+team1+ '</b></td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">' +u13gneongoalsg1+ '</td><td align="center"><b>Goals</b></td><td align="center">' +u13gneonogoalsg1+ '</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">' +u13gneonshotsg1+ '</td><td align="center"><b>Shots</b></td><td align="center">' +u13gneonoshotsg1+ '</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneontopg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Time of Possession</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonotopg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneontop1g1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Time of Possession %</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonotop1g1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonfirstg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>First Touches</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonofirstg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonpassesg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Passes</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonopassesg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonpasscompg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Pass Completion %</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonopasscompg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonnumpassstringg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Number of Pass Strings</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneononumpassstringg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonavgpassstringg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Average Pass String Length</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonoavgpassstringg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonlongpassstringg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Longest Pass String</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonolongpassstringg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '</table>';
 message +=   '</p><p>';
 message += '</body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
 return outRow;
 }
```

Comment: Post some code what you have tried so far.

Comment: Wow, that's hard reading. But I see this bit. 

       `var u13gneongoalsg1 = sheet1.getRange('d'outRow).getValues();// define your range here ;`
Is that you trying to say column D & A row number? outRow has the correct row number?

And have your attempts already matched up what you are looking for in column N

Comment: I have yet to even get this to work at all. First I need to delete all the game#choice, but I have a form that pulls the column of the opponents played and populates a dropdown list.  When you select an opponent I want to search the sheet for that opponent and set the row # so that I can use it to define the individual variables for goals, shots and so forth and then format it and send the email.  What I have is some trial and error that hasn't yielded anything working.

Comment: Sorry Column "N" is the column with the opponent/game that is populated in the form.  So that is the column I want to search in.

Comment: All the data I need from the sheet is in one row starting with column D thru M and Column P thru Y.  I couldn't get the first one to work so didn't change any of the rest.

Comment: I got rid of some of the things in the code that I didn't need anymore.  So the code above shows what I am currently trying to get working.  Very unsuccessfully.

Comment: OK.. I have updated the code.  I have successfully got the row number and it is correct.  Now I need to get the outRow to be part of the range in the variables.  Currently it just returns "Range"  not the info in the cell.  I don't see why that should be.  If I put .getValues the value is blank.

Comment: @Munkey OK.. It all works now with the code above.  When I run the script from the script editor everything works and I get a properly formatted email with all the correct data.  When I use the form the trigger is not running the function.  I have it set to run on form submit.  Look at the execution log and and it doesn't show that it ran.  What am I missing?

Comment: Well I had to add another trigger that was identical to the one that was already there but it now sends the email.  So it all works now.  The code above works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that I got to work for me.

```
    function rowOf(team1, dataRange) {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheetid");
 var sheet1 = ss.getSheetByName("Stats1");
 var dataRange = sheet1.getSheetValues(1,14,300,1);
 var dataRange2 = sheet1.getSheetValues(1,2,300,1);
 var ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById("othersheetid");
 var sheet = ss1.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");
 var data = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
 var email = data[0][2];
 var team1 = data[0][1];
 var magellan = data[0][3];
 var subject = team1 +" Team Stats";
 var outRow = null;
 var outRow2 = null;

  for (var i = 0; i < dataRange.length; i++){

  if (dataRange[i][0] == team1){

     outRow = i+1;

    }
  }


 var Header = sheet1.getRange('d1:y1').getValues();
 var u13gneongoalsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,4).getValues();
 var u13gneonshotsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,5).getValues();
 var u13gneontopg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,6).getValues();
 var u13gneontop1g1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,7).getValues();
 var u13gneonfirstg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,8).getValues();
 var u13gneonpassesg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,9).getValues();
 var u13gneonpasscompg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,10).getValues();
 var u13gneonnumpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,11).getValues();
 var u13gneonavgpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,12).getValues();
 var u13gneonlongpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,13).getValues();
 var u13gneonogoalsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,16).getValues();
 var u13gneonoshotsg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,17).getValues();
 var u13gneonotopg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,18).getValues();
 var u13gneonotop1g1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,19).getValues();
 var u13gneonofirstg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,20).getValues();
 var u13gneonopassesg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,21).getValues();
 var u13gneonopasscompg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,22).getValues();
 var u13gneononumpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,23).getValues();
 var u13gneonoavgpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,24).getValues();
 var u13gneonolongpassstringg1 = sheet1.getRange(outRow,25).getValues();


  var message = '<HTML><BODY><p>';
 message +=   '<table border="1">';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center"><b>U13G Neon</b></td><td align="center"><b>Game Totals</b></td><td align="center"><b>'+team1+ '</b></td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">' +u13gneongoalsg1+ '</td><td align="center"><b>Goals</b></td><td align="center">' +u13gneonogoalsg1+ '</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">' +u13gneonshotsg1+ '</td><td align="center"><b>Shots</b></td><td align="center">' +u13gneonoshotsg1+ '</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneontopg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Time of Possession</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonotopg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneontop1g1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Time of Possession %</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonotop1g1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonfirstg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>First Touches</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonofirstg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonpassesg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Passes</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonopassesg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonpasscompg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Pass Completion %</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonopasscompg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonnumpassstringg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Number of Pass Strings</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneononumpassstringg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonavgpassstringg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Average Pass String Length</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonoavgpassstringg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '<tr><td align="center">'+u13gneonlongpassstringg1 +'</td><td align="center"><b>Longest Pass String</b></td><td align="center">'+u13gneonolongpassstringg1 +'</td></tr>';
 message +=   '</table>';
 message +=   '</p><p>';
 message += '</body></HTML>';

 MailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, "", {htmlBody: message});
 return outRow;
 }
```